# "SignTool error: Access is denied" in TFS 2010 build process

Tags: code-signing, tfsbuild

I'm getting "SignTool Error: Access is Denied" when I attempt to sign a file. When I use an administrator cmd, all works fine. However, this process is going to be used in a TFS 2010 build process and using the InvokeProcess task with signtool gives the same access denied message as a non-administrator command prompt.

More info:

- On a Win2008 R2 enterprise machine.
- User is machine admin and on the domain.
- The TFS Build service is also set to run as this user.
- Using a self signed certificate created using these instructions: [How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows)

After following these instructions I have the following files:

- MyCA.cer
- MyCA.pvk
- MySPC.cer
- MySPC.pvk
- MySPC.pfx

MyCA is in my Trusted Root Certification Authorities
I imported MySPC.pfx into personal certificates, following the advice here: [SignTool error: Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532468/signtool-error-access-is-denied)

To do the signing I'm using the thumbprint of the MySPC.pfx that was imported into the Personal section so my signtool command looks like:

sign /sha1 1e9d7b5ad98552d9c58944e3f3903e6b929f4819 /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll "FileName"

Once again this works in Admin mode. This also works when running cmd as administrator:

sign /f "C:\Code Signing Non-Release\MySPC.pfx" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll "FileName"

New to code signing in general, so any help is welcome.

Comment: Would turning off UAC work if the build service account is already the admin on your build box?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, but with TeamCity. Signtool.exe can sign my .msi, when used in the command line as Administrator, but not from the automated build.

In Windows Server 2008, R2, and 2012, the machine store certificates are actually stored in this folder:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

You will need to give the user which runs the build server READ access to this folder.

Once you've done that, run it again and you'll find it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a permissions problem on the certificate keys - see http://blog.alner.net/archive/2011/11/18/signing-exes-and-msis-with-signtool-via-tfs-builds.aspx