# SignTool Error: Access is denied

Tags: c#, dll, runtime-error, assembly-signing, signtool

I'm trying to sign an external dll with a pfx file using **SignTool** with the below code in cmd.exe

**SignTool sign /f MyCert.pfx /p MyPassword MyControl.dll**

But, I keep getting the following error message.

```
Done Adding Additional Store
SignTool Error: Access is denied.
SignTool Error: An error occured while attempting to sign: MyControl.dll

Number of errors: 1
```

I looked everywhere but couldn't find a correct solution. I tried both the answers listed here, **[SignTool error: Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532468/signtool-error-access-is-denied)** , but keep getting the same error.

I tried all the commands listed here on [Using SignTool to Sign a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but keep getting the same error with every single command.

I'm running cmd.exe as Admin and also I have full ownership of the SignTool.exe folder. In my case, its **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin**

What am I missing here?
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I also tried all the other answers.  In my case the file (EXE) I was trying to sign was marked as read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps looking here [SignTool error: Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532468/signtool-error-access-is-denied)

The strong private key option was the reason the SignTool failed for that user. Not sure if you have it enabled or not?